# SSD Performing Poorly

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, performance

I have a MBP 17 2010, equipped with a Vertex 2 SSD 120GB as boot disk.

It's an old hardware but I don't want to change it, the problem is the SSD is performing poorly :

[image]

The SSD health report is not so bad (except for temperature, which I dont understand) :

[image]

the SATA link looks OK :

[image]

EFI version is the latest :

[image]

but the speed, especially write speed, is quite the half of the Vertex 2 public benchmarks.

Any help ?

Comment: Is this the fastest that SSD has run on this hardware? How full is the drive?

Comment: Yeah is the fastest drive on this hw. It's a fresh install, 100GB free

Comment: I was trying to ask if you have previous benchmarks or if this is the initial speed test you've run with this hardware and that drive. With tens of GB free, you shouldn't be seeing write fragmentation slow downs. Have you tried booting to recovery mode and repairing the drive to see if a TRIM pass helps?

Comment: First test on this Mac. I agree about fragmentation not being a problem. I did "erase free space" from disk utility. I'll try recovery mode and repair, thanks for your help

Comment: I did a disk repair, it was useless. I don't think it does a TRIM pass on the drive. I've already done a "erase free space", which was useless too. Ant other ideas ? :)

Comment: You can't / shouldn't erase free space or zero an SSD. If you do boot to an external drive or boot to recovery HD, a TRIM pass will get run for all Apple SSD - your system info shows TRIM enabled, so YMMV if you used a TRIM enabler and it wasn't recognized natively. Look in Disk Utility's log for a line like **2014-12-30 12:49:21 -0600: Trimming unused blocks.**

Comment: I did a fsck -fy in single user mode, it trimmed the drive. Ti did not help, the problem stills exist.